# Chrome & Firefox keep asking for authentication when going to localhost

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, proxy, localhost

I'm having a problem where Chrome & Firefox have both started bringing up a popup window saying authentication required when going to localhost (401 page).

If I am on the network I can put in my usual network username/password and it works fine, but if I'm offline (the very reason I'm using localhost) that authentication fails and I get sent to a 403 page.

This does not happen in IE and was not happening a few days ago, my network settings are set to ignore Proxy on localhost and auto detect settings is switched off.

Any ideas?

Comment: it's really not depending on browser :) it's server side miss-configuration :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the permission of your site directory. If you put the folder under your home (~), then this problem will probably occurs. Try to give your home folder a wider permission. Especially read permission for Others.

Answer (score 0):

sure, if you browse the `localhost` pure directory you need apache / server authentication

Check your server authentication credentials (user and pass) and this is normal!

while if you browse `localhost/mysite` you will need not an auth ;)

also be sure your `localhost/myproject` folder has **755 chmod**  permissions

finally  check if in your `localhost/myapp/` there is a `.htpasswd` file and post it here

Comment: I'm browsing http://localhost/myapp/welcome.jsp and the authentication popup is coming. Chrome has even be re-installed.

Comment: so check if in your **localhost/myapp/** there is a .htpasswd file and post it here :)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar problem and reinstalling chrome to older version, changing proxy setting didn't help.
I have started using other browsers, however i use the below workaround in case I need to work in chrome.

1.) Click on login without inserting any username and password .
2.) Click on (X) to close the window.

The window would disappear. However, it will reappear if you open any other site or window.